# Pulling information from blizzard API into array in google script

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking for a way to put the information I pull from blizzards API into an array. 
specifically: http://blizzard.github.io/api-wow-docs/#item-api/individual-item

I want to take the array of "bonus stats" and put it into an array in java script.

I can get the item information here:

```
 var itemJSON = UrlFetchApp.fetch("us.battle.net/api/wow/item/18803") 

 var item = JSON.parse(itemJSON.getContentText())
```

The problem is getting that information into a dynamic array.

From the look of their information they pass it comes in the form of an array like this:

```
    "bonusStats": [
    {
        "amount": 15, 
        "stat": 51
    }, 
    {
        "amount": 24, 
        "stat": 5
    }, 
    {
        "amount": 22, 
        "stat": 6
    }, 
    {
        "amount": 25, 
        "stat": 7
    }
]
```

Google uses java script but I am not sure how exactly to create a dynamic array that will accept those values.

Any information you need or assistance you can offer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the bonus stats array into a variable by using dot notation access on the item object.

```
var bonusStats = item.bonusStats;
```

The variable bonusStats will refer to the array you are looking for.

Comment: So this appears to have worked. Except when I pull this data to the spreadsheet in google documents it is blank.

I converted the array to string and it came back 

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Would this be a parsing issue?

Comment: The array is an array of objects, that is why it looks like that when you toString it. I recommend using JSON.stringify(bonusStats)